# I cant link against opengl32 in Windows

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, glfw, glew

I am working on porting an app of mine that I made in OS X to Windows 10. I'm using visual studio 2015 Community Edition.

To get the project running, I need to link against GLFW and, in Windows as I understand, GLEW, since I am targeting GL 4.5.

So I have the glfw and glew libs. I also use Cygwin so I have the libs installed in usr/local/(bin | lib | include) to mimic the folder structure I'd use in OS X for these libs.

The issue I'm having is with the opengl lib itself.

Until yesterday, I had managed to get my project compiling and initializing the glfw window with the following visual studio settings:

**Project->Properties->** :

*C++->General:*

*Additional Include Directories:*

`C:\cygwin64\usr\local\include`

*Linker->General:*

*Additional Library Directories:*

```
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\lib
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin
```

*Linker->Input:*

```
opengl32.dll
glew32s.lib
glfw3.lib
```

The first thing to notice is that I was linking against opengl32.dll, not .lib. I saw a bunch of questions / posts online that state that when you install Windows SDK you have a opengl32.lib in Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows (x86 or otherwise). This is not the case for me. I have even reinstalled the Windows 10 SDK and it does not install any opengl lib, static nor dynamic, anywhere.

So I'm pretty sure that my opengl dll was coming from Windows/System32 because that is the only place in the whole machine where there is any sort of opengl lib.

Which makes me think I might have also had `C:\Windows\System32` in the linker's additional library directories section. I say makes me think, because I had set this up with a lot of struggle about a week ago. Since then I was able to develop just fine.

Last night all I did was commit my work to a git branch, switch to another branch and merge to that branch. After the merge, all Visual Studio linker/C++ settings were wiped. So I had to recreate them, as I showed above.

Now what happens is that if I include `C:\Windows\System32` and the opengl32.dll VS spits out:

```
LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2E0   OpenVRTest  C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll
```

And if I don't include it obviously half the stuff in glfw is unresolved.

Any hints as to how to get this working again? 
It makes no sense to me... It was working just fine and it has to have been working fine with this opengl32.dll

Also as a side note, I'm not sure why people insist that installing the Windows SDK installs a static version of the gl lib; at least it does not for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Linker->Input:
>
> ```
> opengl32.dll
> glew32s.lib
> glfw3.lib
> ```

That `opengl32.dll` is wrong. In Windows development the linker **always** takes `.lib` files. In case of static libraries the `.lib` contains the actual library binary. In case of DLLs the corresponding `.lib` informs the linker about which DLL to use and which symbols it offers.

The main reason for this particular choice of how things are to be done was, that in Windows development it shall be possible to link against a DLL without having the actual DLL around.

Also system libraries always are suffixed `…32` even on 64 bit systems.

Comment: Let's get this the information right. There are two types of static libraries in Windows, both with the extension ".lib". One is used for static linking (this is the kind @SaldaVonSchwartz is looking for) and the other is an import library used for dynamic linking (to by executing process to share code in a DLL). SaldaVonSchwartz, my friend, you are right. I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and with it comes 4 SDK versions. None of which come with the static libraries you're looking for. Blah.

Answer (score -3):

The issue was that among the VS configuration settings that got wiped, were a couple things related to x86 vs x64 platform settings. So the project was now trying to build for 64bit linking against the 32bit dll in System32.

So that's that.

A separate issue is why a lot of answers speak of an opengl32.lib (static) that theoretically comes with the Windows SDK but I have not seen it anywhere. I just link against the dynamic one.

Comment: Fun fact: Even in 64 bit Windows the system libraries are suffixed with `…32`. And in Windows the linker **always(!)** (no exceptions) ingests `.lib` files. In case of dynamically linked libraries this "static" library contains the information, which DLL to link and which symbols it offers.

Comment: In Windows development the `.lib` file does not reside in your system directories, but is part of the compiler distribution. So you can find it somewhere in the directory structure at which your compiler toolchain is installed.

Comment: so why did I get downvoted? lol... 1- yes the issue was that: that my VC settings went to hell and the architecture settings between 64 and 86 were now the same so I was linking against other libs that were 64 and bulding for 32. So not sure how this is not the answer. It is exactly what my problem was. 2- About the dll info inside statics, that's cool to know, but if I tell VS to link against Sysmte32/opengl32.dll it works and if I tell it to link against opengl32.lib it doesn't find it, and I did a search thru all directories and did not find it either.